# Iframe changing size with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to change `iframe` size. This is my html code

```
<iframe id="stream" width="720" height="433" src="#HiddedIt" style="border:0;outline:0" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

And this is my Javascript:

```
if (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth < 1100){
    document.getElementById("stream").width = "485px";
    document.getElementById("stream").height = "295px";
}
```

It doesn't change iframe's size when the user's resolution is lower than 1100. Can you tell where I'm doing a mistake? Thank you.

`if` is working but `iframe`'s size is not changed.

Comment: Is the javascript coming before the `iframe` in the document flow?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question but Javascript is loaded regularly by `<script src="stream.js"></script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is that the Javascript is coming before the `<iframe>` in the HTML.  The browser parses the HTML in a sequence.

Without seeing your actual document, I can only imagine that you're calling the Javascript in the `<head>` and creating the `<iframe>` in the `<body>`.

The problem with this is that when the Javascript in the `<head>` is executed, there's no `<iframe>` created yet, so there's no object for it to change!

One solution is to call your Javascript in the `<body>` after the `<iframe>` is created. Alternatively, you can use `window.onload` to run the script after the `iframe` has been created:

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (
        window.innerWidth < 1100 || 
        document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1100 || 
        document.body.clientWidth < 1100
    ){
        alert("Yes");
        document.getElementById("stream").width = "485px";
        document.getElementById("stream").height = "295px";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the JQuery library for Javascript to resize the IFRAME programmatically.

In the code below the value "#iframe" would be the ID of your IFRAME. Then you can plugin the height value which just sets the CSS height for the IFRAME.

```
$("#iframe").css("height", "50px");
```

You can use .css to set any CSS value.